# Retina bug ? Containing div does not expand 1000px width div

Tags: html, css, ipad, width, retina-display

I was just about to release a webpage. Then i thought, why not see how it works on an iPad with Retina. The page did not look very good. The problem can be reproduced by visiting the link with an iPad Retina http://www.banksalg.no/retinabug.php

If you look at the border on the right side, you can see that it stops around 20-30 px from the right side of the screen. The green color in the border is actually the body background color. If you make the `div`s smaller than 1000px, for example 900px it acts as it should.

You can only see this error on an iPad Retina. The error is not visible by using any "how a website looks on a retina screen" application/emulator.

For me it almost seems like the iPad cannot handle 1000px width. It should when the resolution is 2048px. So at least 1024 px width should be possible.

Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't set a viewport. By default, Safari on iOS sets a logical viewport width of `980px` (per [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/UsingtheViewport/UsingtheViewport.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006509-SW27)).

Add:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
```

to your document's `head` to use the full logical device width.